# How to execute remote command/s as other user without root permissions?

Tags: linux, ssh, bash

I am writing a bash script to gather up the whereabouts of certain files on several hosts. I've gotten to a point where I can logon using ssh, execute several commands but on some hosts but on several hosts I need to switch to a different user.

The issue that I'm having is because I am not a root user, neither is the user that I need to switch to. So I keep getting prompted for passwords or errors that I am not allow to because I am not a root user.

1. how do I input my own password only one time?
   I am not a root user, neither is the other user. I suppose I need to use 'sudo su' but I do I feed the prompt my own password?
   I have tried using expect and echo -e "pwd" | sudo -S
2. su to a different user and have it execute the command/s?

So far I have:

```
#!bin/bash
...
# works fine
output=$(ssh -q $USER@host "whoami;whoami")
...
# prompts for pwd and executes command after exiting the new shell
output=$(ssh -t -q $USER@$host "sudo su - otheruser ; whoami"
...
```

Comment: You can configure `sudo` to let you execute certain commands as another user, optionally without having to enter your password. Alternatively you could arrange for your ssh key to be added to the other user's authorized_keys file so that you can login to the system as that user, a fixed command can be forced with authroized_keys as well.

Comment: @wurtel: Thanks! Unfortunately I cannot change any of the configurations.

Comment: @wurtel, you should give that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run a command as another user using sudo configured to allow you to access the other account  use

```
sudo -u otheruser yourcommand
```

and your password.

To get a shell using another user using their password use

```
su -c "yourcommand" otheruser
```

sudo will cache the password, su will not. You may start a shell with either of the commands and execute everything you need to do before you logout if you want to avoid typing the password multiple times.

Another thing:
`sudo su` is an antipattern and `sudo su - otheruser` even more, as it uses`su` just to start a shell. `sudo bash` (or what shell you use) would be the same.

If you want to get a shell from sudo, use `sudo -s` (shell) or `sudo -i` (login shell).

Comment: thanks! I have modified the bash script to: "echo "secret-pwd" | ssh -t -t -q $USER@$host "sudo -u otheruser <command>" and this works.